# Mirror Maker 2 Translate Consumer offsets

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I am working on kafka mirror making and I am using MM2. I can able to start the mirror process and all topics and date are replicated from source to target cluster.

I need to start the consumers in target cluster from where it has been left off in source cluster. I came across RemoteClusterUtils.translateOffsets to translate the consumer offsets from remote to local.

On checking the code, I can see that it just consumes the checkpoint topic and returning the offset for the consumer group we provided and it does not commit the offset.

Whether we need to explicitly commit the offset using OffsetCommitRequest and start the consumers in target clusters or whether some other way for this?

Comment: Note: Tune into Kafka Summit next week on session about MirrorMaker 2

Comment: Hope your problem is solved in Kafka `2.7.0` with https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9076